# is it possible to get portfolio balance data from any Coinbase account without using api?

Tags: api, blockchain, bitcoin, coinbase-api, coin-change

**is it possible to get portfolio balance data from any Coinbase account using only email or without using coinbase api.
please help me. i need this method to make an software . that help me to show my . all account balances without any api.**

Answer (score 1):

No. Account information is not visible without signing the request with an API key or using the authorization address and OAuth2. Both options require the API

[api-key-authentication](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/api-key-authentication)

> API Key authentication should only be used to access your own account. If your application requires access to other Coinbase users' accounts, do not use API Key. To securely access other Coinbase users' accounts, use Sign in with Coinbase (OAuth2)

[OAuth2](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/sign-in-with-coinbase)

> The Coinbase API allows developers to use the OAuth2 protocol to allow a Coinbase user to grant a 3rd party application full or partial access to his/her account, without sharing the account’s API key or login credentials. It is a slightly more complex integration than the API Key authentication method, but is more flexible. OAuth2 works well for web applications, as well as desktop and mobile apps.